# iPhone/iPad fatal error in C++ code produces no output in the log

Tags: iphone, c++, ipad, ios, logging

I'm trying to move away from Objective-C to C++ for audio in my iPad programming, due to the a few reports I've heard of Objective-C selectors sometimes causing audio glitches. So I'm starting to use pure C++ files.

When a fatal error happens in one of the C++ files, I get no output from the log. The app just crashes.

For example, if I do this in my C++ file:

```
    env = new ADSR();
    cout << "setting env to null\n";
    env = NULL;
    env->setSustainLevel(1);
    cout << "called function on non-initialized env\n";
```

I get the following output:

> setting env to null

After that, there's a method called on NULL, which apparently kills the app, but absolutely nothing to that effect is reported. What do I need to do to have useful information logged when there's an error in my C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using breakpoints and tracing the game flow using the Debugger? I think using these would definitely give some log!!

Comment: I have been worked on debugging couple of crash logs of games completely written in C++ for iphone. If there were no traces how could any one debug that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try.

1. You can set NSZombie to `enabled`.
2. Perhaps you can link your file against Foundation Framework and use NSLog to debug the crash.
3. Also, if you compile to a device, you can check the Device Console and the Error Logs in Xcode's Organizer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: NSZombieEnabled is for Objective-C objects only.

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course, the console. The main mac console has a crash report for my app, with a beautiful stack trace for the error, including specific line numbers in my C++ file.

Answer (score 0):

The mac's console app provides great information on why my crash happened. Thanks to Moshe for getting me most of the way there by suggesting I look at the console if I was running the app on a device.